# Strange characters appearing when accessing document library

Tags: document-library

I'm experiencing trouble when accessing a SharePoint document library. When clicking into the document library from the 'View all site content' area within the web GUI, I'm confronted with the following (no site actions menu etc):

[image: Text displayed when opening the document libary]

I've never seen anything like this before, and as a result I'm struggling to find the right set of key-words to search/troubleshoot an error like this via the web.

Has anyone got a solution? At worst we plan to restore an instance of the virtual machine from a back-up, save a copy of the library from that machine, and then upload a new copy of it to the production instance. It'd be nice however if I could fix the issue with the existing one instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further investigation, I ended up mapping a drive to the library and was able to view the contents. It would seem that someone had used a password safe variant called KeePass, which had encrypted some content within the library, resulting in the above jargon.

Luckily however, we managed to get the required document out of explorer, and can now import it into a newly created library within the environment.

Hopefully this helps anyone else in a bizarre situation with characteristics like this.